# Return the index of the first occurrence of ch in s

Tags: python

Given string s and single-character string `ch`, return the index of the first occurrence of ch in s.

For example, where `('abc', 'b')` should return 1.
If `ch` is not in `s`, return `-1`.

String methods are not allowed to be used.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What have you done so far? Give us a snippet of your code. [Click here to learn how to ask a good question](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbyZHZmOHPAhVNwmMKHZbyBV8QFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AFQjCNEDXp3Jt0aiEKFPFI03PFSjhs3gAw&sig2=aXmdP2tKS9huoS09qXb0nQ&bvm=bv.135974163,d.cGc)

Comment: Show a [mcve] of your own attempt at this. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please make sure you show your effort, so the community can assist.

Comment: Just as a hint , if you don't want to use predefined python functions you can do it using `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function similar to `str.index()` that returns index on finding the first match of the passed character. In case of no match, raises `ValueError` exception. For example:

```
def get_index(my_string, my_char):
    for i, s in enumerate(my_string):
        if s == my_char:
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> get_index('abcd', 'c')
2
>>> get_index('abcd', 'z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in get_index
ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) docs:

```
def find_ch(s, ch):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if ch == c:
            return i
    return -1
print(find_ch('abc', 'd'))
print(find_ch('abc', 'b'))
>> -1
>> 1
```